# hadoop map reduce vs clojure pmap function

Tags: hadoop, clojure, mapreduce

Supposedly i have large independent sets of data in seperate excel files.

In terms of runtime efficiency, would it be better to use clojure Pmap function to process the data or hadoop map reduce?

Each excel file consists of about 34000 rows at least and i have quite a large number of them.

Sorry for the beginner question as i am relatively new to both and are doing research on them

As some of you guys have explained,

Perhaps one more question would be to compare clojure pmap against instance of running multi instances of the same copies of software, what are the differences between those?

The only thing i can think of is that pmap can take any amount of variables however, reading one file per instance of applications would require the number of files to be known upfront and the instances be initialized

Comment: See: [Do I need SQL or Hadoop? A Flowchart](http://www.aaroncordova.com/2012/01/do-i-need-sql-or-hadoop-flowchart.html) - s/SQL/pmap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say use Hadoop, but not directly, but rather through [Cascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog) from Clojure. The value proposition here is all that Hadoop gives you plus the great declarative query language (which may well make using Cascalog worthwhile even if the task is relatively small; setup with Hadoop in local mode is completely hassle-free).

The original introductory blog posts are still the best starting point (although there's great documentation available now -- see the wiki at GitHub): the first one is [here](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/introducing-cascalog-a-clojure-based-query-language-for-hado.html) and it links to the second one at the end.

To give you a taste of what it looks like, here's a snippet from the first tutorial (finding all "follow" relationships where the follower is older than the person they follow):

```
(?<- (stdout) [?person1 ?person2] 
  (age ?person1 ?age1)
  (follows ?person1 ?person2)
  (age ?person2 ?age2)
  (< ?age2 ?age1))
```

No problem running this on a cluster too, see [News Feed in 38 lines of code using Cascalog](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/news-feed-in-38-lines-of-code-using-cascalog.html) on Nathan Marz's blog for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go running and establishing an Hadoop cluster just to be able to process a lot of small files (which is not ideal for Hadoop anyway). Hadoop is geared towards handling large files (its block size is 64M) and the map reduce efficiency comes from letting having these large files distributed over the cluster and sending the computation to the data.

In your case it seems that running multiple copies of your software each processing one file at a time would solve the problem and would have the least overhead - both computational and operational (ie. setting up and maintaining  hadoop).

One thing that hadoop can give you  is the management of the processing task, that is retires in case of failure etc., but again, it seems and overkill for what you describe

Comment: @arnon.me Hi, how about clojure pmap functionality as compared to running multiple copies of the same file?

Comment: If you have a lot of files which are relatively the same size you can gain enough parallelism by just handling as many files as you have cores even if each files is handled by a single core. If the files have a big variance in size or you only have few files  it can be worth to parallize the handling of individual files and if the processing is really CPU intensive it might be even worthwhile to pay the price of handling a file in a distributed manner (e.g. by hadoop) - it all depends:)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of languages have map reduce capabilities, including Clojure.

I'd say that Hadoop would be the hands-down winner because it manages it over clusters of machines.  It's the potential for massive parallelization that would give it the clear edge over anything else that didn't have it built in.

Comment: Is there a situation whereby clojure outwits hadoop? Supposedly running on little resources say maybe a few PCs instead of clusters of machines?

Comment: "outwits"?  Sounds like you're guilty of magical thinking now.